# select a value and charge the method result in a text_field + Jquery and Ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-selectors, textfield

could you help me please?

I'm newbie on Ruby on Rails and I'm having troubles to show information in the form when I select an option. Someone told me that I needed to use Jquery, even though I haven't gotten this to work

I need to select a month, and in the Text_field (meta) I need to appears the method results but I don't know what else I need to do.

I have this:

```
class Logind < ActiveRecord::Base

  def mejora(mes)
    if mes == 1
    "#{estado}".parameterize
    else 
      @meta = "#{meta}".to_i          # @meta -> variable de instancia
      @estado = "#{estado}".to_i
      @peorE = "#{peorE}".to_i
      puts @mejora = (@estado + ((@meta - @peorE)/11))
    end
  end
```

Logind controller

```
class LogindsController < ApplicationController

  # GET /loginds/new
  def new
    @logind = Logind.new 
    @logind.mejora(:mes)

  end
```

In the views:

_form.html.erb

```
        <%= form_for(@logind) do |f| %>
          <% if @logind.errors.any? %>
            <div id="error_explanation">
              <h2><%= pluralize(@logind.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this logind from being saved:</h2>

              <ul>
              <% @logind.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                <li><%= message %></li>
              <% end %>
              </ul>
            </div>
          <% end %>

          <div class="field" id="meta">
            <%= f.label :Meta %><br>
            <%= f.text_field :meta %>
          </div>
```

new.html.erb

```
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <section class="col-sm-4">
                    <%= form_for(@logind) do |f| %>
                        <% if @logind.errors.any? %>
                            <div id="error_explanation">
                                <h2><%= pluralize(@logind.errors.count, "error") %> prohibido este registro para ser guardado:</h2>

                                <ul>
                                <% @logind.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                                    <li><%= message %></li>
                                <% end %>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        <% end %>

                        <% mes = {:Enero => 1, :Febrero => 2, :Marzo => 3, :Abril => 4, :Mayo => 5, :Junio => 6, :Julio => 7, :Agosto => 8, :Septiembre => 9, :Octubre => 10, :Noviembre => 11, :Diciembre => 12} %>
            <div class="field"> 
                    <% lista = mes %>
                    <%= f.label :Mes %><br>
                    <%= f.select :mes, lista, {include_blank: "- Elegir mes -"}, {:class => 'logbymonth'} %>
            </div>
                    <% end %>
                </section>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <section class="containerWaterMark">
                    <h1>Nuevo registro de indicador</h1>

                    <%= render 'form' %>
                </section>
            </div>

            <div>
                <%= link_to 'Atrás', loginds_path, class:"btn btn-default" %>
            </div>
```

---

application.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.logbymonth').change(function(){
    var month = $('.logbymonth').val();
    $('#mes').val('month');
});
```

});

Thank you for your help!

Comment: do you mean this result "@mejora = (@estado + ((@meta - @peorE)/11))" needs to appear in the "meta field" ?, if so, you have to make an Ajax request in your 'change' function, so that when the user selects the month, the Ajax request is going to be fired, here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ you can find how to make ajax requests. You will also need to expose the "mejora" somehow, for that, you will need a controller, in the controller you will need to call that method and return the result perhaps in JSON format. Good luck my friend, keep reading, don't give up.

Comment: perhaps, if you won't do anything fancy in ruby, you don't even need to make an ajax request, looks like you'r just doing some basic math. In that case, do the math in the 'change' function, and update your #mes field.